# How to copy properties from application.yml file to logback.groovy class

Tags: grails, gradle, groovy

I added some properties in `application.yml` `sentry.dsn=xxxxxxx`
I now need to read it in logback.groovy So I used `def sentryDsn = Holders.config.sentry.dsn`
But  `Holders.config` is null. It seems that config is not loaded before logback.groovy is executed. Anyway to do it?

Comment: What's the use case of needing the dsn for sentry in logback.groovy? If you use the sentry plugin it should take care of all the setup.